# editar ficheiro docx e guardar em PDF em php

Tags: php, pdf, microsoft-word

Tenho um ficheiro docx, o meu objectivo é conseguir editar o docx, editar uma string específica (fazer algo do género do str_replace), e por fim guardar o ficheiro em PDF. O docx como é um ficheiro zipado xml, estou a pensar editar a partir daí. Ou aconselham outra solução mas simples?

Agora para guardar de docx para PDF é mais difícil, não estou a encontrar nenhuma biblioteca gratuita que me faça isso em condições.

Existe uma maneira mais fácil para fazer este processo? Existe alguma biblioteca que faça isto?

Answer (score 1):

Usa a biblioteca PHPDOCX = http://www.phpdocx.com/ e https://github.com/benskay/PHP-Digital-Format-Convert-Epub-Mobi-PDF/tree/master/library/phpDocx, que tem a versão paga e gratuita também.

Abrir o arquivo docx:

```
require_once 'phpdocx_pro/classes/TransformDoc.inc';
    $docx = new TransformDoc();
    $docx->setStrFile('document.docx');
    $docx->generateXHTML();
    $html = $docx->getStrXHTML();
```

E para exportar para pdf usa:

```
$docx->generatePDF();
```

Comment: mas a biblioteca PHPDOCX é paga. Estava interessado numa gratuita

Comment: @pc_oc não é paga, tem duas versões a com licença LGPL e Pro, esta ultima sim é paga, como o henrique disse (*que tem a versão paga e gratuita*).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas a versão gratuita deve ser limitada

Comment: @pc_oc então só resta mesmo o `phpoffice/phpword` :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu na altura acabei por fazer tudo em html e converter para PDF uma vez que foi a única solução que encontrei na altura. Foram cerca de 40 páginas que tive que fazer..

Answer (score 1):

Sobre a resposta do [@henriquedpereira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86240/3635), o PHPdocX tem duas versões a com licença LGPL e a Pro, a primeira é gratuita (atenção licença LGPL) e a ultima sim é paga. *PHPdocX free* permite gerar dinamicamente arquivos docx com opções de formatação simples, como listas, numeração de páginas e tabelas, marcas d'água não são inseridas no período de teste ou limite na quantidade de documentos que pode gerar. Se a marca d'água não for um incomodo já atende a sua necessidade.

No entanto existe uma ótima biblioteca para acessar arquivos Office, é o [PHPOffice/PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Para instalar adicione ao `require:` do seu `composer.json` (é necessário ter o [`dompdf`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) também para escrever o PDF):

```
{
    "require": {
        "dompdf/dompdf": "0.6.*",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "v0.13.*"
    }
}
```

E depois execute no terminal ou cmd:

```
cd c:\wamp\www\projeto
composer update
```

Para converter um Word para PDF você precisa apenas importar a bibliotecas (será necessário usar `composer`), segue um exemplo (fonte: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord):

```
<?php

require_once 'bootstrap.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;

Settings::setPdfRendererPath('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

$temp = IOFactory::load('pasta/doc.docx');

$xmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($temp , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('pasta/doc.pdf', true);
```

**Infelizmente** na versão [1.3.0](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#0130-unreleased) foi removido definitivamente o autoloader customizado, o que permitia instalar sem `composer` a biblioteca, sei que parece uma situação difícil, entendo que o `composer` parece complicado, mas na verdade ele é mais fácil de estruturar um projeto do que manualmente, fora que se precisar atualizar algo, adicionar ou remover o `composer` faz isto pra você.

- http://tableless.com.br/composer-para-iniciantes/
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md