# Possibilidade de visualizar doc,docx no navegador

Tags: php, javascript

Existe alguma biblioteca que consiga visualizar documentos(doc,docx) para ser visualizado no navegador em um uma intranet sem que precise de recursos externos como o google docs ou office live?
Preciso de algum componente que não precise acesso externo.

Comment: Creio que não, a não ser que você implemente uma solução como a api do Google Docs, para abrir como um documento no navegador vocÊ pode usar isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346117/how-can-i-view-open-a-word-document-in-my-browser-using-with-php-or-html

Comment: @lvcs é necessário um plugin instalado no browser para visualizar o doc através da solução posta na resposta deste link, a não ser que ele faça o que vc citou acima, implementar com o Google Docs. Entretanto, se o usuário não for editar o arquivo seria melhor usar o formato PDF, pelo menos os browsers já dão suporte para ele.

Comment: Entendo o questão que não podemos impedir o upload de anexos do tipo doc ou docx e existe uma necessidade de verificar esses arquivos. Busquei em alguns locais e algumas pessoas convertem pra pdf para visualizar no navegador ai to buscando como fazer dessa maneira.

Comment: Outra opção é ao fazer upload você enviar o arquivo para alguma api de cloud, hospedando la o doc, e a partir dai, pegando o link dele e mandando para a api do google docs

Comment: @lvcs Mas seguindo essa linha estaríamos preso a uma solução externa que com o google docs resolveria.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: @ThallesDaniel mas cumpre o objetivo que é renderizar mesmo que seja em servidor local

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Se o caso é apenas visualizar

Solução *pratica*, se é para renderizar apenas, converta para  PDF, isso tecnicamente resolve muito problema de compatibilidade entre diferentes navegadores e até mesmo ausência de plugins ou activex (Internet Explorer), pois hoje os browsers populares já tem embutido nativamente leitores de PDF:

- Google Chrome (ou navegadores baseados no Chromium) tem o *Chrome PDF Viewer*
- Firefox tem o PDF.js (que pode ser usado para até mesmo no client-side)

Navegadores mobile aparentemente já tem API interna embutida que para PDF que faz visualizar

- Soluções alternativas (retirado de [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/1518921)):

  Office 365:

  ```
    <iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src={URL DO DOCUMENTO}"></iframe>
  ```

  Usar google docs:

  ```
    <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url={URL DO DOCUMENTO}&amp;embedded=true"></iframe>
  ```

> **Nota:** troque `{URL DO DOCUMENTO}` pela URL desejada

No entanto você pode implementar com PDF.js em qualquer navegador moderno e até customizar o visualizador as suas necessidades, exemplo bem simples:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115789/3635

### Usando de conversão do lado servidor

Apesar de eu realmente acreditar que o melhor seja já enviar no formato PDF para o servidor de produção pelos seguintes motivos:

- Nem toda conversão será perfeita usando conversores no lado do servidor
- Se fizer a conversão previamente usando o próprio MSWord (ou outro office) que geralmente já tem add-on nativo para salvar como PDF e enviar.

Todavia ainda sim você pode querer fazer a conversão no servidor, se o servidor for um linux é instalar o [unoconv](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/), alguns linux terão isto via repositório, com um `SSH` e `apt-get` ou `yum` talvez consiga instalar, as distros suportadas:

- Red Hat
- Debian
- Fedora
- Mandriva
- Ubuntu Lucid
- OpenSUSE

Ou você pode compilar no servidor:

- http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/unoconv-0.7.tar.gz
- https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv

> **Requisitos:** unoconv requer Python e necessita do LibreOffice ou OpenOffice com [**UNO**](https://www.openoffice.org/udk/).

Um exemplo de uso no terminal:

```
$ /home/compilado/unoconv /home/user/meudocumento.doc
```

Em PHP você pode usar:

```
<?php

//Seta o arquivo que será convertido (pode ser um arquivo vindo de um upload)
$input  = '/home/user/meudocumento.doc';

//Define aonde será salvo
$output = '/home/user/meudocumento.pdf';


//Caminho do executável acaso não esteja global, se estiver global basta setar 'unoconv'
$exec = '/home/compilado/unoconv';

//Escapar os argumentos (este é necessário para evitar problemas com espaços e acentos)
$inputarg  = escapeshellarg($input);
$outputarg = escapeshellarg($output);

//Executa o comando
$resultado = shell_exec($exec . ' -f pdf -o ' . $outputarg . ' ' . $inputarg);

//Resposta da conversão
var_dump($resultado);
```

### PHPOffice

Como expliquei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100798/3635, o PHPOffice oferece tal suporte

Para instalar adicione ao `require:` do seu `composer.json` (é necessário ter o `dompdf` também para escrever o PDF):

```
{
    "require": {
        "dompdf/dompdf": "0.6.*",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "v0.13.*"
    }
}
```

E depois execute no terminal ou cmd:

```
cd c:\wamp\www\projeto
composer update
```

Para converter um Word para PDF você precisa apenas importar a bibliotecas (será necessário usar `composer`), segue um exemplo (fonte: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord):

```
<?php

require_once 'bootstrap.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;

Settings::setPdfRendererPath('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

$temp = IOFactory::load('pasta/doc.docx');

$xmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($temp , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('pasta/doc.pdf', true);
```

> Se estiver usando o PHP7, existe um BUG https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/732, todavia na versão *dev* do repositório o problema já foi corrigido:
>
> ```
> {
>     "require": {
>        "phpoffice/phpword": "dev-develop"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Usar repositórios/branchs em desenvolvimento pode ser um risco, recomendo que teste bem antes.

Comment: Um detalhe pelo pacote office a fidelidade é bem maior que pelas bibliotecas php to vendo isso agora

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51412/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-possibilidade-de-visualizar-doc-doc)