# Como visualizar docx e pdf diretamente no navegador?

Tags: php

Eu tenho um sisteminha de cadastro de arquivos (docx, pdf) em php, atualmente esses arquivos ficam salvos em um diretório, e o caminho fica salvo no banco (mySQL), eu exibo esses arquivos através de um `href`, dando para BAIXA-LOS.

Como faço para abrir/visualizar esses arquivos diretamente no navegador do usuário ao invés de baixa-los?

Código:

```
<td><a style='color: Blue' href='uploads_psi/janeiro/".$cont['janeiro']."' download target='_blank'>".$cont['janeiro']."</a></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nada garante que ele será visualizado, mesmo que você force via `.htaccess` todos documentos do tipo `docx` a usarem isto:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i)(doc|doc|xls|xlsx)$">
Header set Content-Disposition "inline"
</FilesMatch>
```

Só garante que você informou que quer `inline`, mas se o usuário tiver como padrão no **navegador "dele"** para baixar este tipo, então você não tem nenhum controle sobre isto, afinal não tem sentido controlar a máquina do cliente, ele decide o que ele quer fazer com o download HTTP (falo download da resposta HTTP, não de baixar o arquivo para uma pasta).

Outra coisa **muito importante**, o navegador não visualiza stand-alone arquivos do Office, quem faz isso são plugins de terceiros, então alguns programa de office instalam plugins no seu navegador, antigamente os navegadores não barravam isso, mas hoje os navegadores estão mais espertos, logo se um programa como o MSOffice tentar instalar um plugin/add-on/extensão no navegador do usuário é bem capaz de isto ser barrado.

As vezes o browser detecta coisas como office e consegue fazer o "bind" entre navegador e office, mas isso não é regra e não é obrigação do navegador, alguns o fazem simplesmente por conveniência.

Então pra resumir, mesmo que o usuário tenha o Office instalado no PC dele não significa que o navegador vai conseguir usar ler o documento na tela, o que acaba ocasionando o download direto, já que arquivos não reconhecidos pelo navegador sempre são baixados.

Então mesmo que você remova o atributo `download` a tag `<a></a>` e tente ajustar o `Content-Disposition: inline` com htaccess nada vai garantir que seus usuários conseguirão visualizar.

Qual a solução alternativa? Você (hipoteticamente) me pergunta.

A resposta é, usar um formato suportado por diversos navegadores e sistemas operacionais, incluindo até mesmo celulares tablets, e este formato é o:

> PDF - Portable Document Format

Note que PDF vai funcionar na maioria dos navegadores e celulares, desde que sete o `Content-Disposition: inline`, algo como:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i)(pdf)$">
Header set Content-Disposition "inline"
</FilesMatch>
```

Mas isto só porque felizmente os navegadores modernos veem com leitor de PDF embutido, se for um navegador muito alternativo ou for um navegador antigo então é provavel que não visualize, no caso do Firefox, Edge e Chrome, todos tem visualizador de PDF embutidos.

Comment: @SamuelVerissimo veja este https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100798/3635

Comment: @SamuelVerissimo Se o composer for complicado para ti experimente esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176004/3635 - 
a parte dos Iframes, assim não precisará converter, mas eu não sei dizer se estes serviços estão disponíveis.
Cria uma página nova php, coloca na URL assim `ver.php?documento=http://meusite.com/local/doc.docx` (é um exemplo)
E no conteudo do ver.php coloca: `<iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['document']); ?>"></iframe>`

Comment: Se não funcionar tente este: `<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=<?php echo urlencode($_GET['document']); ?>&amp;embedded=true"></iframe>`

Comment: @SamuelVerissimo o chat demora a chegar as mensagem no inbox, só chega rapido se ele estiver aberto. Vou deletar as mensagens acima.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar alterar o `header` e utilizar a função `readfile()`.
Se você estiver fazendo seu projeto com algum *framework*, aconselho você criar uma rota, se você não utiliza nenhum, você pode criar um arquivo (exibir-arquivo.php) para fazer o tratamento do arquivo e exibi-lo.

Basicamente você vai fazer o seguinte:

```
$filePath = 'arquivo.pdf';
$fileName = 'arquivo.pdf';
$mimeType = 'application/pdf'; // Esse valor deve ser dinâmico, você deve pegar ele de acordo com o tipo de arquivo, PDF, DOCX e etc.

header("Content-type: {$mimeType}");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($fileName);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, esse `'arquivo.pdf'` está vindo da onde? substituo ele por o que?

Comment: Será um parâmetro que você passará via `$_GET`.

Comment: Hmmmm, não estou sabendo como aplicar ao código... **listagem_relatorio_psi.php** como está: `<td><a style='color: Blue' href='exibir-arquivo.php".$cont['janeiro']."' target='_blank'>".$cont['janeiro']."</a></td>` o que devo fazer?

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Tente remover da tag o `download target`, apenas assim:

```
<td><a style='color: Blue' href='uploads_psi/janeiro/".$cont['janeiro']."'>".$cont['janeiro']."</a></td>
```

Obs: Dependendo do tipo de arquivo o navegador não conseguirá exibí-lo.

Comment: Não funciona, como já havia comentado... os arquivos são docx e mesmo assim acontece o download.